# Sharepoint 2016 - NerioCluster : No lease returned when reading DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016

I have this error appears repeatedly in ULS viewer!

> **Search Product - NerioCluster: No lease returned when reading DB.**

All the services application including Search application are working normally but I don't know why to keep getting this error!

Any help how to solve it.
Thanks.